# Can i save a rails form values multiple times in database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, simple-form

I dont know is it possible but i have a form and when i submit the form, i want the records to be saved multiple times in database. As of now, i am not worried about efficiency , but to get this thing going.

`@message = Message.new`

```
<%= simple_form_for @message do |f| %>
 <%= f.input :description, as: :text, input_html: {rows: 7}, label: false, placeholder: "Type your    message ..." %>
 <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-info" %>
<%end%>
```

I want the above form to be saved multiple times, like (i know its dumb)

```
for i in 1..4
 @message.save
end
```

**Intention:**
My intention here is to send a single message to all group members at once. So i have the `group_id` and `description` now and when users submits the form, i want to iterate over all the users who are following the `group_id` and save the records with respective `user_id's` who all are following group.
I dont think i need validation for this.

Comment: yes u can do that. But whats the need ?

Comment: You'll definitely need to add context on WHY you're trying to do this.  You could run into all kinds of problems, like uniqueness validation, if you're blindly saving records

Comment: basically i want to send a message to all group members at once...so i will replace the `user_id` column in messages model with group members id and save it.

Comment: Why not just send each user the same message? No need to duplicate them.

Comment: @diego.greyrobot, yes i would like to do the same, so in my messages model, it has `group_id`, `user_id`, `description`, so respective columns will get updated for each user. After sending the all group message at once, i would like to add sending group message to selected members as well

Comment: @SahilGrover can you please tell how ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `group_id` in the form so I'm not sure if it's somewhere else but you claim to have it so I'll just assume you do.

```
@group = Group.find(group_id)
@group.users.each do |user|
  message_params = params[:message].merge(user_id: user.id)
  Message.create(message_params)
end
```

Comment: is there any solution w.r.t my code mentioned ? simply saving form values multiple times.? `group_id` is what i am getting as parameter

Comment: No where in your code does it show group_id would be a parameter as it's not in your form. I'm not entirely sure how it would be a parameter with the code shown. However, if it is, then you would just use the code I gave you but use `params[:group_id]` instead of `group_id`.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE**

So I did some digging, and found out that this is not as trivial as I originally thought.

When you call `@message.save`, rails will go behind the scenes to check if that record is a new record (i.e. call `@message.new_record?`) If it is not a new record, it will update the existing one instead of creating a new one. If you can override that, you could save the record multiple times.

The issue I found when trying to set the `new_record` attribute directly was it is only called on initialization ( when `@message.new` is called) and if the record does not get initialized then `new_record` defaults to false.

As others have pointed out in comments, there really shouldn't need to be a reason to save an identical record (which is why rails doesn't easily allow it). If you want to assign the same message to multiple users, set up associations to relate the two models. If you need to use the same message every time you do something, create it once then simply fetch it from the database whenever you need to use it.